# Removing break lines using Shell Scripting

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to remove the break lines from this:

```
Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4
Test1,Test2,Test3,
Test4
Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4
Test1,Test2,Test3,
Test4
Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4
```

To get:

```
Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4
Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4
Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4
Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4
Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4
```

But I'm only getting:

```
Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4, Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4, Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4, Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4, Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4, Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4
```

I'm using the following code: `tr '\r\n' ' ' < test.txt`

Comment: You don't want to remove all line breaks. You just want to remove the line breaks when the next line starts with `-`.

Comment: You can't do this with a simple tool like `tr`, write an `awk` script to do it. It will need to save each line in a variable without printing it. Then when it reads the next line, if it begins with `-` it prints the two lines combined, otherwise it just prints the previous line and saves the current line in the variable.

Comment: What are the exact criteria for when two lines should be merged, and when they shouldn't?

Comment: @GordonDavisson it is only an example to clarify what I want to get it. It isn't a pattern or something similar.

Comment: @JavierMuñoz There must be some criteria for deciding when to leave lines alone vs merge them. Juan Carlos Migliavacca's answer assumes you want to skip a line, merge the next two, skip one, merge two, etc repeating forever. Your initial version suggested that lines starting with "-" should be merged with the preceding line, but your exit changed that. The current version suggests that maybe lines ending with "," should be merged with the next line. Which (if any) rule is correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the input file is called text.txt this command with GNU sed will solve it:

```
sed 'n;N;s/\n//' text.txt
```

[image: bash output]

### The explanation:

```
n:      # If auto-print is not disabled, print the pattern space, then, 
        # regardless, 
        # replace the pattern space with the next line of input. If there is no 
        # more 
        # input then sed exits without processing any more commands.
        # This command is useful to skip lines (e.g. process every Nth line).

N;      # Add a newline to the pattern space, then append the next line of
        # input to the pattern space.  If there is no more input then 'sed'
        # exits without processing any more commands.

s/\n//  # delete the first newline
```

You can read more in the official documentation: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#sed-regular-expressions

Comment: It doesn't work. By the way, I've modified the example to clarify it.

Comment: Try sed 'n;N;s/\n//' text.txt, (i removed a space in the command).

Comment: Thank you too much! It works perfect! Could you explain it with more details?

Comment: Ive added a brief explanation for you. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Sed variant is good but not obvy even with explanation
Take a look at this variant with variable substitution

```
text=$(cat test)
echo "${text//,$'\n'/,}"
```